# All prime ideals are maximal - Counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I would like to know of some simple counter examples to the statement "ALL prime ideals are maximal" I say counter examples because I think the statement isn't true.

Comment: Can you think of an integral domain which is not a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you might want to recall that in a domain $\{0\}$ is a prime ideal. Thus, if you have any non-zero prime ideals you have your examples.

Perhaps, you however meant non-zero prime ideals that are not maximal. 
This is also not difficult to find.

Take a polynomial ring, over som field, in several variables like $k[x,y,z]$. 
The ideals generated by $\{x\}$, by  $\{x,y\}$ and $\{x,y,z\}$ are all prime and only the last one is maximal.

Answer (score 3):

Easy counterexample: consider $\langle x \rangle \subset \Bbb Z[x]$.  Alternatively (following quid's idea), consider $\langle x \rangle \subset \Bbb C[x,y]$.

Remember that an ideal is maximal in $R$ if and only if $R/I$ is a field, and that an ideal is prime in $R$ if and only if (it is non the entire ring and) $R/I$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Or $\langle p\rangle$ for any prime $p$.

Comment: It is in my experience highly unusual to insist that prime ideals are non-zero (they should not be the full ring/domain though).

Comment: @quid is it?  I thought I saw that in Atiya but I'm a bit out of practice

Comment: @quid or maybe it's your second statement that I'm thinking of.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just checked. They write "$p \neq (1)$."

Comment: @quid thanks, I appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome. On a semi-serious note: it is good you have the modified condition in brackets; else somebody might come along and say it is redundant as a domain must not be the zero ring anyway.

Comment: Even without knowing the stuff about quotient rings of prime and maximal ideals, it is still east to see that $(x)\subset (x,2)$ and both are prime. So in this way I see this as the simplest example.

Comment: @MatthewLevy Thanks, I obviously like this example.  I think quid's is also easy to see.  I thought the other stuff was useful intuition in case OP wanted to hunt for more counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, but i am relatively new to commutative algebra and I  can't see how $<x>$ is maximal? Surely there is no other ideal which is strictly between $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $<x>$?

Comment: You mean how it's *not* maximal. Try adding in even constants, for example.

Comment: That is, consider $(x,2)=(x)+(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal of $\mathbb{C}[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$ can be thought of as a system of polynomial equations, and as such can be associated to its set of solutions in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Prime ideals correspond to irreducible such loci, and by Hilbert's nullstellensatz there's a one-to-one, order-reversing correspondence between prime ideals and irreducible subvarieties of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Consequently, a *maximal* ideal in $\mathbb{C}[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$ is simply the ideal consisting of all polynomials vanishing at a single point.  On the other hand, a *prime* ideal is the ideal of polynomials vanishing on some irreducible subvariety, say a curve or surface in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

So, to get an example, just take your favorite curve or surface or whatever in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and take the ideal of polynomials that vanish on it.

Comment: Do you honestly think that if he can't think of a counter-example on his own he knows enough algebraic geometry on $\mathbb C^n$ to do that?

Comment: The point of the answer was to expose him to algebraic geometry, without which commutative algebra feels almost nonsensical.

Comment: Clearly, but you didn't answer the question at all to any sort of level that he could comprehend.

Comment: Why do you think that?  He clearly knows a lot of math if he's formulating his own questions about prime ideals, and there's nothing here above a high-school level that I'm not just giving to him as a black box.  If there's anything unclear to him he's free to ask me a question in the comments.

Comment: I also think the answer is appropriate provided it is amongst other answers.  Answers benefit not only the OP in the short-term, but readers of all levels in the long-term.

Comment: agree with Kaj. this is really good answer. it does not deserve "-1", i think. so +1

Answer (score 0):

I dont give example; but I want to say where you can  find them:
Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. then *$R$ is an Artinian ring* iff "*ALL prime ideals are maximal*". So in any noetherian ring which is not Artinian, (in other words: any noetherian ring of positive dimension), there will be prime ideals which are not maximal.
So you will find them for example in $\Bbb Z$ and $k[x_1,\cdots , x_t]$. think about minimal prime ideals

Comment: You should correct this since $\mathbb Z$ has all prime ideals maximal.

Comment: $0$ is prime ideal but not maximal

Comment: Oh okay, true. Was thinking the OP wanted some non-trivial examples.